# ¿Cómo importar y leer una librería en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

estoy haciendo un "inicio de sesión" en html y javascript. Soy novato.
La idea sencilla y facil para mi tarea es introducir nombre de usuario y email como inputs y, si los datos son correctos, se redirige al perfil del usuario.
Mi idea es hacer una libreria.text, que serviria como base de datos, donde estan todos los nombres de usuario e email. Esto con el fin de imporatrlo al archivo html o JS y hacer una condicion:

Si el nombre de usuario y email que se introdujo como inputs son correctos:
Se hace un loop y una condicion en cada loop.
Ejemplo:
1r loop: Se lee la primera linea de la libreria y se compara con los inputs (No coinciden)
2o loo: Se lee la segunda linea de la libreria y se compara con los inputs (No coinciden)
Y asi hasta tener una coincidencia.

Sé que no es la solución más elegante, pero repito, soy novato y este trabajo no es más que una tarea de colegio.

Además, de momento tengo esto:

**index.js**

```
var User_Name= document.getElementById("UserName");

    function Redirect(){
        if (User_Name!==null || User_Name!==""){
                window.location = 'google.com'; //este seria el url de perfil
            }
        }
```

y el documento html es:

```
<body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <form action="">
        <div> //input de Nombre
            <label for="UserName">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="UserName">
        </div>
        <div> //input de email
            <label for="UserEmail">Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="UserEmail">
        </div>   
        </form> 
    <input type="button" onclick="Redirect()" value="Enter"/>
    </body>
```

Comment: Desde aquí vamos con un fallo de seguridad enorme: No puedes guardar usuarios, contraseñas, emails en un _.txt_, imagínate que alguien acceda a ese archivo y vea todo ¿No sería correcto, verdad? Para registros, login, etc, normalmente se usan bases de datos MySQL. Por otro lado, no puedes modificar archivos con JavaScript, necesitas obligatoriamente un lenguaje de backend, con AJAX.

Comment: Lo se, pero eso requiere mas nivel, algo que no se me exige en la lista de tareas. Se supone que el .txt "actua" como esa base de datos que se registran automaticamente cuando un nuevo usuario se registra. Además, teniamos que subirlo a un servidor en concreto pero ya no esta operativo, asi que en internet no estará :D

Comment: Dices que tendrás un fichero `.txt` que simulará la BD, pero que no habrá Internet, entonces, ¿cómo o desde dónde vas a leer esos ficheros? La pregunta tiene la etiqueta de `html`, por lo que no es un ejercicio de node. ¿Cómo tienes pensado leer las líneas de ese fichero para hacer la comprobación de credenciales (simulación de login)?

Answer (score 0):

Te agrego un ejemplo usando un arreglo de objetos. Hice un par de correcciones, están comentadas en el código.

```js
function Redirect() {
    // Se debe leer el valor del input dentro de la función de lo contrario
    // el valor será undefined.
    // se debe acceder a la propiedad value ya que ahí está el 
    // valor ingresado.
    var User_Name = document.getElementById("UserName").value;

    if (User_Name !== null || User_Name !== "") {
        // iterar el arreglo de usuarios
        for (let i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i++) {
            // evaluar si el nombre coincide
            if (User_Name == usuarios[i].username) {
                window.location = 'google.com'; 
            }
        }
    }
}

// arreglo con objetos que guardan los datos de cada usuario
// esto reemplaza a un txt
let usuarios = [{
        username: 'juan',
        email: 'juan@correo.com'
    },
    {
        username: 'juan1',
        email: 'juan1@correo.com'
    }
]
```

```html
<body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <form action="">
        <div> //input de Nombre
            <label for="UserName">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="UserName">
        </div>
        <div> //input de email
            <label for="UserEmail">Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="UserEmail">
        </div>   
        </form> 
    <input type="button" onclick="Redirect()" value="Enter"/>
 </body>
```